# How to save a change to an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have to make a program that reads the number of seats and stores it in a two dimensional array. The empty seats is hashtag and if the user buys a seat it becomes *. The odd rows have 15 seats and even have 20. 
When I purchase a seat, it puts the * on the seat but when I buy another seat it removes it and puts * on the newly purchased seat. How can I make it so it saves the * that it prints on every seat.

Global

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int column2, row2,total = 0;
    char ab[20][15];
    char EMPTY = '#';
    char FULL = '*';
    int seat = 300;
    int seat2 = 0;
    int Quit = 1;
    int choice;
    int cost,answer,price;

void ShowSeats()
{    
    cout << "\tSeats" << endl;
    cout << "       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            ab[i][j] = EMPTY;
            if (i % 2 && j == 14) // 0 is false, 1 is true
            {
                break;
            }
            if (i == row2 && j == column2) // assuming these numbers start from 0
            {
                ab[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        cout << endl
             << "Row " << (i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

            cout << "  " << ab[i][j];

        }
    }
}



int main()
{

while (true){    
    cout << "Please select the row you would like to sit in: ";
    cin >> row2;
    cout << "Please select the seat you would like to sit in: ";
    cin >> column2;
    cout<< "Enter the price";
    cin >> price;
    if (ab [row2] [column2] == '*')
        {
            cout << "Sorry that seat is sold-out, Please select a new seat.";
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cost = price;

            cout << "That ticket costs: " << cost << endl;
            cout << "Confirm Purchase? Enter (1 = YES)";
            cin >> answer;
            seat = seat - answer;
            seat2 += answer;



            if (answer == 1)
            {
                cout << "Your ticket purchase has been confirmed." << endl;
                ab [row2][column2] = FULL;
                total = total + cost;
                cout << "Would you like to look at another seat? (1 = YES)";
                cin>>Quit;
            }
    ShowSeats();
    }


}}
```

It shows me this when I purchase row 2 and seat 2
https://gyazo.com/0d8bd7ed02e969110db47b428c512f24

But when I purchase row 2 seat 3 it does not save the previous purchase and I want it to save both.
https://gyazo.com/f865ba7145d1fafac246836975f2ee00

Comment: The question is incomplete. Make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For starters, `ab` is declared in `Show_Chart`, but you are also using it in other functions?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have declared it as global.

Comment: Rather than use a global, you could make `ab` a vector of vectors, and pass it by reference to Show_Chart.  That would also let you have different rows be different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Show_Chart`, you are doing:

```
ab[i][j] = EMPTY;
```

for every `i` and `j`. This means the old values are erased every time you call this function.

Remove that line to avoid overwriting saved seats.

To initialize all the seats before asking for any user input, you can do this in `main` before entering the `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) 
            ab[i][j] = EMPTY;
```

Comment: Yes I realized that and I have removed it although it still does not show the * on the sold seat. However, it is not allowing me to buy the seat again.

Comment: Then we can't really address your issues till you make a MRE. Show what inputs you are providing to your function, and where the output differs from what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please open it again.

Comment: Your question is still incomplete. No one can reproduce your results with just the provided code.

Comment: I have made the reproducible sample. can you please open the question and assist me with the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I do this it is not showing the hashtags for the blank seats. How can I make it so that it shows # for blank seats but when purchased shows * for sold seats.

Comment: You need to initialize it the first time only. Just do that in `main`. Edited the answer.